# loop code not working as it keeps throwing errors

Tags: python, html, selenium, loops

So as someone suggested on a previous post to this issue, I have indented *everything* by four spaces, as the code I am using was created by another user and I am copying and pasting, to preserve the indentation. I also tried saving the original code to py file before executing as someone else suggested and I still get errors, pasted below at the bottom of the code.

```
def races(main_url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(main_url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    races = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('time-location')
    races = [race.text[:5] for race in races]
    races = [race.replace(':', '') for race in races]

    driver.close()

    return races

def scrape(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('racecard-ajax-link')[1].click()

    WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//* [@id="tab-racecard-sectional-times"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button')))

    for horse in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-item'):
        horseName = horse.find_element_by_class_name('form-link').text
        times = horse.find_elements_by_class_name('sectionals-time')
        times = [time.text for time in times]
        print('{}: {}'.format(horseName, times))
    print()

    driver.close()

def main():
    date = '6-October-2018'
    main_url = 'http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Wolverhampton/' + date
    for race in races(main_url):
        url = main_url + '/' + race
        print(url)
        scrape(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\djcro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\testing1.py", line 40, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Users\djcro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\testing1.py", line 34, in main
    for race in races(main_url):
  File "C:\Users\djcro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\testing1.py", line 2, in races
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined

Comment: Take a look at your import... maybe you are missing something

Comment: you are getting that error because you didn't import webdriver (see my comment on Maciej's answer).  After you add the imports, you should remove the implicit waits and never mix them with explicit waits.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to add "from selenium import webdriver", assuming you're using selenium.

Comment: Nope all the imports have already been done:                                                     from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

Comment: @BrianC this is the correct answer.  The stacktrace you posted in the question shows `webdriver.Chrome()` is being called on line #2 of `testing1.py`.  Therefore it's not possible that you have included these imports at the top of the `testing1.py` file.   Calling webdriver without importing it will result in `NameError`, just like error shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

driver = webdriver.Chrome() - This is incorrect.

You need to pass the chrome driver executable like below

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/of/the/chrome/driver/executable")

Comment: you don't need to pass the location of the executable if it exists on your path.